# Azure Dev Ops pipeline java project

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops

How to set a task in Azure pipelines so that it only builds when changing to a newer version of the app, i.e., for example, I change the pom to a more recent version, it should be built and deployed, some classes should be added, files should not be built, deployed.

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Please check whether the following answer can help you and feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use path filter to trigger a build only when pom file was changed

```yaml
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - my-module/pom.xml
```

You can find more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths)